# Filtering out results obtained by using GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT name, SUM(p.column1+p.column2+p.colum3) AS PICKS
FROM table AS p
WHERE date = '2014-09-10'
GROUP BY name
```

This query works perfect. Would I would like is to filter out results where `p.column1+p.column2+p.column3 = 0`

I have tried:

```
SELECT name, SUM(p.column1+p.column2+p.colum3) AS PICKS
FROM table AS p
WHERE PICKS > 0
AND date = '2014-09-10'
GROUP BY name
```

But it keeps telling me that there is an incorrect use of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Please rename your title to something more indicative of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use having clause to filter out the results of aggregate functions

```
SELECT name, SUM(p.column1+p.column2+p.colum3) AS PICKS
FROM table AS p
WHERE date = '2014-09-10'
GROUP BY name
HAVING PICKS > 0
```

or you another way you can use sub select

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT name, SUM(p.column1+p.column2+p.colum3) AS PICKS
FROM table AS p
WHERE date = '2014-09-10'
GROUP BY name) t
WHERE PICKS > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a having statement. Not a where.

```
SELECT name, SUM(p.column1+p.column2+p.colum3) AS PICKS
FROM table AS p
AND date = '2014-09-10'
GROUP BY name
HAVING PICKS > 0
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: I added it not even ~ 60 seconds after you did.

Comment: Also a typo in your query after from table use where not and :)